# BDD Testing Account Login MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bdd, specflow

I have an MVC Application (Lang. C#). I am trying to learn how to use BDD Testing with SpecFlow.

I am trying to create a test that 'Asserts' if the correct Username/Password is entered, then a page will load (or Authentication is given), and if the Incorrect Username/Password is entered then (no authentication is give).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Selenium WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) - you can use the C# bindings to drive the browser, and interact with your web app.

[Here's a good example](http://anoopjshetty.wordpress.com/2012/02/08/creating-test-automation-framework-using-c-selenium-and-nunit/) to start with.

[Second example](http://anoopjshetty.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/test-automation-framework-in-page-object-pattern-using-c-selenium-specflow-and-nunit/), specifically demonstrating an approach for writing SpecFlow tests with Selenium, using the Page-Object pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have looked into this a little bit, im more struggling to find how to link my test project to the specific parts of my MVC App.

Comment: All you need is to have the MVC app running *somewhere*. For example, if running locally at http://localhost/myapp (which is the login page), all you need to is navigate webdriver to that URL, and then using the webdriver api, find and populate the username & password inputs on the page, then find and click the "login" button. The example I linked to shows the basics of that - all you're doing is using WebDriver to automate a browser to interact with your web app (mimic what an end user does)